# How do I configure this DotNetNuke database?

Tags: asp.net, .net, dotnetnuke

I'm attempting to use the install wizard to install DotNetNuke 4.09.03. (I am using an old version as a requirement of what I'm doing).

I'm not very familiar with ASP or how to set up this connection. Below I have attached the form and what it asked of me.

[image: DotNetNuke Database Connection Setup]

What do I enter into these fields? I'll be using SQL Server 2005.

Could someone help me understand what I am entering in these fields? I am using discountasp.com as my host, in case you need that information.

Thank you all ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 choose the second radio button.

If the SQL Server is a local server (meaning on the web server) put "." in for the Server: field otherwise put in the IP Address

On the second field put the name of your database (you'll have to create one)

You will likely uncheck the Integrated Security checkbox and enter the username/password for the connection to SQL server. (you'll likely create this as well)

Don't worry about the db owner or object qualifier settings.

Check out some of the installation videos here http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Training/Tutorials.aspx even though they are for newer versions of DNN